# Can't instantiate Stopwatch class in My Code

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am using Silverlight 5 , and .NET 4.5 in my Visual Studio 2012 solution, 
I can't do :    using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.
I find in msdn that it's supported when using .NET 4.5 framework
If someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: Missing a reference to System.Diagnostics? Add Reference

Comment: Can't instantiate means? Tell what happens? What is the error?

Comment: The `using` directive should only have the namespace: `using System.Diagnostics;`, then you can `new Stopwatch();`

Comment: I can't reference System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch in Silverlight Application which not the case when i reference it in the Web hosting project

Comment: I honestly think the `Stopwatch` class is missing in Silverlight, and the MSDN documentation is incorrect. I have decompiled the relevant SL assemblies and cannot find any `Stopwatch` class. Please have a look [here](http://www.abtsoftware.co.uk/News/tabid/93/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/17/Drop_in_replacement_for_SystemTimersTimer_and_Stopwatch_in_Silverlight.aspx) for a potential replacement.